# Documentation of Drupal Content Types and Views

Tags: views, 7

Drupal 7, Views 3

Ok, I've got a bunch of content types and views, all working happily together, what would be really nice is a way of automatically documenting things, say a printable page of what fields are in a content type or what fields are used in a view. Searching on Google gives lots of info on creating document types but I haven't been able to find anything on actually creating documentation.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `admin/reports/fields` - Field list with node type relationships.
- `admin/reports/fields/views-fields` - Used in views.

You need Field UI module enabled.

Comment: That helps. Doesn't print so nicely but it's a start, thanks.